# the mail function is not active on my intranet website

Tags: php, email

I've just built a website for my company and have placed it on a server. It's working perfectly. The website contains a form page that collects request from staff. The form sends the information to the database. I placed code there for it to send a mail to my inbox so that I can be notified after a staff member fills the form. Unfortunately, the mail doesn't get to me. Please I need help on how to go about it.

I am using XAMPP at my back end. Below is the code that involves the mail part:

```
<?php
$to = "seyioyedeji31@yahoo.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "<html>
<head>
    <title>MIS HELP SUCCESSFUL</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Here are the query details:</p>
    <p><table border=1 style= background:#0B0B61>
       <tr><td> SENDER: $_POST[fullname]</td></tr> 
       <tr><td> DEPARTMENT: $_POST[department]</td></tr>
       <tr><td> NATURE OF PROBLEM: $_POST[nature]</td></tr>
       <tr><td> DETAILS: $_POST[mail]<td></tr>
       </table></p>

</body>
</html>";

$from = "seyioyedeji@mis.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mail could be broken at any number of points. Without knowing more, these are the points that come to mind:

- There is no local mail agent to route mail from the box to the next mail relay.
- PHP wasn't configured with email support that xampp might need.
- The box has no outbound mail rights. ACL, firewall, etc.
- The email is getting sent out, but is being delivered to a local account on the server.
- Your email provider is filtering out the email as spam.

Edit:

After a bit of looking, looks like this might be of help:

http://expertester.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/how-to-send-email-from-xampp-php/

which is based on another's solution from:

http://egrasp.wordpress.com/2010/02/03/sending-email-in-php-using-xampp-lite-1-7-3-on-windows/

But looks like XAMPP has its own special email sending configs. :)

If you want to configure XAMPP to deliver via localhost, you may need to install a local email service like postfix to handle outbound delivery, which is what I would normally do on a host. Though only have it listen on localhost to avoid abuse by spammers.

Normal localhost tests I would run:

```
uptime | mail you@email.address.com
# replace 'mail' with mailx, sendmail, etc. depending on what you have installed.
```

But that presumes you have a local mail handler installed.

Comment: this is my first time of doing this on the intranet. I av tried so many things, i even edited the php.ini file but i changed it back to the original state, i tried using smtp servers but i noticed it will only work for the system where it is installed, what about other users on the intranet. Please tell me what exactly i need to do because i need to fix it. Am getting the information on my database but i need a notification which is very important.

Comment: edited my answer with some test to try out, if you haven't already.